# Toshiba 32 GB won't format

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a Toshiba flash drive that I'm trying to wipe clean, but the thing is that the files won't go away.
I have tried everything:

1. the simple left click -> format, a message appears: windows can't complete the format process
2. disk management and deleting the partition, once I create a new partition the files appear back as if nothing happened
3. `DISKPART` command in CMD, once I hit clean it says the process was successful but the files are still there, it should be mentioned that `CHKDSK` doesn't show anything out of the ordinary
4. third party software: mini partition tool, Rufus, easeus, I've tried wiping data by putting 0's which is an option in mini partition tool, but this doesn't seem to be solving anything
5. virus scan with esetnod shows no signs of malware
   am

I missing something? is there anything I can do?

Comment: Chuck it. This is a common failure mode of flash memory, both usb sticks and sd cards. You don't lose any data but the drive is effectively useless.

Comment: Also look at the "linked questions" in the duplicates. Hosed memory often *seems* to work, which is an effect of disk caching, but the memory chips themselves are read-only.