# Write Protected USB

Tags: usb, read-only

i have run into these problem a few times already. Basically my Kingston DT50 gave up when i tried making bootable windows 7 install. It went into read only mode (write protected) and i just cant remove it.

It does not have physical button so it's not switch that locked it into read only mode.
I tried diskformat and a few other formatting tools including some on on linux.
Tried regedit thing on windows
Tried official kingston formatting tool
Hell even some 3rd party formatting tools.

No dice on any of the ways above. Im pretty sure flash drive detected some error and locked itself to preserve data, now my question is these. Is there any way i can short pin it to reboot or just reset its data. Or maybe even remove/bypass some part to allow writing to it. I dont care if i damage it even more in process, just want to try and save it (even if its not worth it :D)

Comment: See all the duplicates at https://superuser.com/questions/1471774/toshiba-32-gb-wont-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) They're not worth fighting once they start to play up.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but as you can see in my post i already know about those "solutions" and as mentioned above i already tried them. What im looking for is bypassing write only protection on hardware/software level on flash drive itself even if that is unsafe for data on it (current or future).